# How to create sprite animation using winapi c?

Tags: c, winapi, sprite

How to create sprite animation using winapi without gdi?
im trying to do this:

```
Sprite(hDC, L"fon.bmp",150, 14, 30, 30, SRCCOPY);

void Sprite(HDC hdc, CHAR* Path, int x, int y, int Width, int Height, DWORD rop)
{
    HBITMAP bmp = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, Path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    SelectObject(memdc, bmp);
    BitBlt(hdc, x, y, Width, Height, memdc, 0, 0, rop);
}
```

How i can change frame?

Comment: *"without gdi"*? First of all: Why? The code you have is using the GDI, and the GDI will give you the performance you need for a simple sprite animation. If you insist on not using the GDI, go with [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) or [Direct2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990.aspx)/[Direct3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309466.aspx). Other than that, it's not at all clear, what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Create a vector and place frames of the animation. Then using some sort of timer, erase the screen and bitblt the next frame's image. This is common way of doing frame based animation and there is nothing specific for winapi.

Comment: Erasing the whole screen is overkill, you can just erase the previous rectangle of sprite.

Comment: If there are overlaps, easiest method is to erase everything. Obviously this decision can be altered if bitblt is too slow

Comment: There is no faster block transfer than `BitBlt`. If it is too slow, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: OpenGL or DirectX works faster but obviously that's not GDI. I remember switching from GDI to DirectX for the first time. Speed up was remarkable.